# Why does my transaction fail when exceeding a certain amount of inserts?

Tags: c#, sqlite

I am attempting to insert a large amount of data into a SQLite database using a transaction.

```
using (var transaction = database.BeginTransaction())
      {
          foreach(var i in Enumerable.Range(0, _wordCount))
          {
              statement.CommandText = $"INSERT INTO Hashes (word, hash) VALUES ('{words[i]}', '{hashes[i]}')";
              statement.ExecuteNonQuery();
          }

          transaction.Commit();
      }
```

The above code works great for smaller amounts of data in the 10 - 12k range, however, anything exceeding the 12k mark seems to crash with the following error

```
'SQL logic error near "d": syntax error'
```

Resources online indicate that there shouldn't be a limit as to how many inserts you can accomplish via a single transaction so it would make sense for the transaction to function as per normal regardless of the number of inserts

Is there anything I am missing or any reason why my transaction could possibly be failing when exceeding 12,000 inserts?

Comment: Does it only happen when you are inserting more than exactly 12 000 records ?

Comment: Not exactly 12,000. It crashes somewhere between 12,000 and 12,400

Comment: My guess is that one of the words contains a single quote. In any case, please use parameters.

Comment: Yeah, use prepared statements with placeholders instead of inserting unknown text directly in a query. That's why you're getting the syntax error. (I just ran a script that inserted nearly 300,000 rows in one transaction, btw. Your problem has nothing to do with transactions or limits or anything like that.)

Answer (score 0):

Solved by using parameters as recommended by Dirk and Shawn

Comment: ideally, you should always use params and not concatenate strings as it stops SQL injection in certain scenarios.